# Converting millions, billion, and trillion to a number in Python

Tags: python, regex, formatting

I have a column that has values like '5.00 M', '1.00 T', and '1.29 Juta' and would like an easy way to just convert that into a numerical value. I tried

```
import re
powers = {'M': 10 ** 9, 'T': 10 ** 12, 'Juta': 10 ** 6}
var1 = ['4', '7149', '6184.09', '0.00', '8', '134944', '5187.33', '5.00 M', '17', '74104', '60773.22', '260.00 M', '7', '347334', '451922.68', '1.00 T', '80', '18469', '483386.83', '2.50 M', '12', '4716', '14946.30', '0.00', '18', '7119', '111617.66', '0.00', '31', '23131', '814413.09', '0.00', '21', '16281', '192020.50', '0.00', '20', '98381', '57850.37', '0.00', '31', '12501', '39384.40', '0.00', '31', '2851', '1.29 Juta', '0.00', '34', '9440', '171364.82', '0.00', '26', '25442', '54394.00', '0.00', '24', '2492', '165295.95', '0.00', '12', '675', '51301.40', '0.00', '7', '5', '8057.77', '0.00', '6', '704', '35579.19', '0.00', '5', '2133', '15683.20', '0.00', '3', '1356', '5021.00', '0.00', '3', '966', '5456.32', '0.00', '5', '2636', '4097.42', '0.00', '8', '1878', '4554.50', '0.00', '6', '3518', '13900.00', '0.00', '2', '1', '61000.00', '0.00', '3', '0', '1688.00', '0.00', '4', '10', '1488.33', '0.00', '0', '0', '0.00', '0.00', '0', '0', '0.00', '0.00', '2', '0', '4054.00', '0.00', '0', '0', '0.00', '0.00']

def f(num_str):
    match = re.search(r"([0-9\.]+)\s?(M|T|Juta)", num_str)
    if match is not None:
        quantity = match.group(0)
        magnitude = match.group(1)
        return float(quantity) * powers[magnitude]

for i in var1:
    x = f(i)
    print(x)
```

But I got this error:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-8dd2f89076c3> in <module>
      1 for i in var1:
----> 2     x = f(i)
      3     print(x)

<ipython-input-22-cb419bc71fb8> in f(num_str)
      7         quantity = match.group(0)
      8         magnitude = match.group(1)
----> 9         return float(quantity) * powers[magnitude]

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5.00 M'
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `group(1)` and `group(2)`, as `group(0)` has the [entire matching string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects):

```
import re
powers = {'M': 10 ** 9, 'T': 10 ** 12, 'Juta': 10 ** 6}
var1 = ['4', '7149', '6184.09', '0.00', '8', '134944', '5187.33', '5.00 M', '17', '74104', '60773.22', '260.00 M', '7', '347334', '451922.68', '1.00 T', '80', '18469', '483386.83', '2.50 M', '12', '4716', '14946.30', '0.00', '18', '7119', '111617.66', '0.00', '31', '23131', '814413.09', '0.00', '21', '16281', '192020.50', '0.00', '20', '98381', '57850.37', '0.00', '31', '12501', '39384.40', '0.00', '31', '2851', '1.29 Juta', '0.00', '34', '9440', '171364.82', '0.00', '26', '25442', '54394.00', '0.00', '24', '2492', '165295.95', '0.00', '12', '675', '51301.40', '0.00', '7', '5', '8057.77', '0.00', '6', '704', '35579.19', '0.00', '5', '2133', '15683.20', '0.00', '3', '1356', '5021.00', '0.00', '3', '966', '5456.32', '0.00', '5', '2636', '4097.42', '0.00', '8', '1878', '4554.50', '0.00', '6', '3518', '13900.00', '0.00', '2', '1', '61000.00', '0.00', '3', '0', '1688.00', '0.00', '4', '10', '1488.33', '0.00', '0', '0', '0.00', '0.00', '0', '0', '0.00', '0.00', '2', '0', '4054.00', '0.00', '0', '0', '0.00', '0.00']

def f(num_str):
    match = re.search(r"([0-9\.]+)\s?(M|T|Juta)", num_str)
    if match is not None:
        quantity = match.group(1)
        magnitude = match.group(2)
        return float(quantity) * powers[magnitude]
    else:
        return num_str

for i in var1:
    x = f(i)
    print(x)
```

Comment: Another problem is that the regex requires 0 or 1 spaces (no more) and it fails if there isn't an `M` `T` or `Juta` suffix.

Comment: I got ```None
None
None
None
None
None
None
5000000000.0
None
None
None
260000000000.0
None
None
None
1000000000000.0
None
None
None``` for the result, what if I want None to be the same as the value in var1?

Comment: Add an `else:` to deal with the case where the regex doesn't match?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the wrong group numbers, your regex still has some problem.  You can fix it as follows:

```
def f(num_str):
    # regex below has been replaced
    match = re.search(r"(\d+(?:.\d+)?)\s?(M|T|Juta)?", num_str)    # added a ? after Juta) and replaced regex for numeric part.
    if match is not None:
        quantity = match.group(1)
        if match.group(2):                # added a test before to check if magnitude exists
            magnitude = match.group(2)
            return float(quantity) * powers[magnitude]
        else:                             # added a else condition for without magnitude
            return float(quantity)
        
for i in var1:
    x = f(i)
    print(x)
```

In fact, your regex `[0-9\.]+` for the numeral part is not correct.  It is better replaced by using  `\d+(?:.\d+)?` with `\d+` as the integral part and optional fractional part  `(.\d+)?` with the fractional part enclosed in `(?:   )` to make it a non-capturing group.